# How does data flow through bridged ports in linux

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, bridge

I have three networking ports on my server. One motherboard port and a dual port Intel Pro1000 attached by a PCIe slot. All of these have been bridged together to make a diy switch. I tried checking the number of interrupts during a transfer through the server but there were only a few per second. I can't figure out if the data is processed by the CPU or bypasses it. Can someone explain how the data flows from one Pro1000 port to the other and to the motherboard port when the data is going *through* the ports but is not destined for the server itself.

```
         CPU/RAM
            |
            | 
            |  PCIe
         --------------
         |             |
         |             |
         |           Motherboard Port
      Intel Pro1000
      |          |
      |          |
    Port 1     Port 2
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [Direct Memory Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)?

Comment: There's SW bridging and HW bridging; it depends on the HW and the SW's support for the HW. In that regard, it's specific to details which you don't provide.

Comment: What more details could I supply?

Comment: @txtechhelp I'm familiar with the concept but wasn't sure if it is used in this context. So you're suggesting each port can handle basic packet switching decisions and then drop the payload right into the memory area for the next port? Would some kind of interrupt be needed to tell the destination it has new data in its buffers?

Comment: @chewsocks, well it's actually the kernel (linux) doing the switching, but with DMA, the kernel doesn't have to signal an interrupt to fetch the newly available data from the controllers (which are just pushing/pulling signals). DMA allows the kernel to access the memory being used by the drivers/controllers to handle the flow of packets without interrupting the CPU to do so.

Comment: @txtechhelp Aren't you mixing up two conceptual levels here? Could you show us a single ethernet hardware with which the kernel would have to fetch all packet data one by one via interrupts? I hope not. Performance would be lousy. On the other hand, one interrupt per data packet is going to occur, otherwise the kernel would have to poll for data -- not an option with today's frequency scaling schemes. -- Also, bridging is not for free. Bridges usually learn via which port a specific target address can be reached.

Comment: @chewsocks The dual-port card may be capable of performing the switching functioanlity autonomously (but probably only after a respective initialisation), if it can reach the target for a packet received on one port via its other port. In this regard, your Q's title is inaccurate (or suggesting a dependency which is not necessarily there).